# Cannot sign in iCloud nor iMessage, faceTime on 10.11.1 for upgraded admin account

Tags: macos, icloud

Many people had such issue:
https://discussions.apple.com/message/29295728?ac_cid=tw123456#29295728

I notice when upgraded to 10.11.1, I cannot login any iCloud nor iMessage/faceTime account on my old and sole admin account.

I tried to delete ~/Library/Application Support/iCloud/accounts, no luck

I tried to erase NVRAM, no luck

I tried safe mode, no luck

I tried to reset key chain, no luck

I managed to rerun setup assitant and create a new admin account, now I can login to my iCloud.

iCloud always says You can't sign in at this time, try signing in again

iMessage will pop a window ask me again to enter password after I entered it when entering the account name and password, and then says Verification Failed, An unknown error occurred.

Version:
10.11.1

So.. I am desperate, and I think it is supposed to be some broken files for my old admin account, but I don't know what files to be deleted to let OS X to create new files to restore the state.

Comment: Try this one - way too much to retype in here - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7272123

Comment: no luck.. I also found https://discussions.apple.com/message/29296108?ac_cid=tw123456#29296108, seems same, but the solution in that post does not work too

Comment: "no luck" ? You didn't have time to do all of that.

Comment: @Tetsujin I started doing it since yesterday, I just try what I missed in your link…